# JPA ORM Design Patterns

Tags: design-patterns, orm, jpa

I need new design patterns in JPA/ORM instead of POJO/JDBC/DAO patterns.
Is there any recommended link?

RGDS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the examples I've seen, JPA doesn't fundamentally change design patterns for Java EE, it's a standard implementation of persistence. You can (should, depending on your constraints?) still hide the persistence implementation behind a DAO layer - maybe the transition is a good test of whether your existing DAOs are doing a good job of hiding those implementation details.

There's an tutorial that does that on [developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ejb3jpa.html). There's also a discussion about whether [JPA killed the DAOs](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/09/jpa-dao) on infoq that you might find of interest.